# AWS CDK create Lambda from image

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, amazon-ecr

I am a new to AWS world. I am working on a project to build a server less application and as part of that I have created 4 lambda which works fine.

Next I am trying to create a deployment pipe line using CDK; below is what I am trying to do.

1. create an docker image with code that includes all lambda code
2. create 4 different lambdas from same image just override the CMD in docker image and mention the lambda handler

I have setup CDK locally and able to create stack, everything works fine.

Below is my code snippet

--create the docker image

```py
asset_img = aws_ecr_assets.DockerImageAsset(
    self,
    "test_image",
    directory=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "../mysrc")
)
```

--create lambda from docker image

```py
aws_lambda.DockerImageFunction(
   self,
   function_name="gt_from_image",
   code=_lambda.DockerImageCode.from_ecr(
       self,
       repository=asset_img.repository,
       tag="latest")
)
```

Below is the error I am getting

`TypeError: from_ecr() got multiple values for argument 'repository'`

I am not sure how I can reference the image that was created and define the lambda.

Solved: Below is the solution

asset_img = _asset.DockerImageAsset(self, "test_image",                                            directory=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "../gt"))

```
_lambda.DockerImageFunction(self, id='gt_from_image', function_name="gt_from_image_Fn",
                                    code=_lambda.DockerImageCode.from_ecr(
                                        repository=asset_img.repository,
                                        tag=asset_img.source_hash))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-lambda.DockerImageCode.html#static-fromwbrecrrepository-props) for `DockerImageCode.from_ecr()`, it does not expect a scope argument, so your `self` argument is what is causing the error.

Another issue is that `DockerImageAsset` will not tag the image as `latest`, as that is against AWS best practices.

The easy way to achieve what you are doing is to use
[`DockerImageCode.from_image_asset()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda/DockerImageCode.html#aws_cdk.aws_lambda.DockerImageCode.from_image_asset).

Comment: Thanks.removed the self and CDK is uploading the Stack but fails to create Lambda with below error message.
Code -->
asset_img = _asset.DockerImageAsset(self, "galactus_transformer_image",
directory=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "../galactus_transformer"))

_lambda.DockerImageFunction(self, id='gt_from_image', function_name="gt_from_image_Fn",                                    code=_lambda.DockerImageCode.from_ecr(repository=asset_img.repository))

Resource handler returned message: "Source image xxxxxx.dkr.amazonaws.com/aws-cdk/assets:latest does not exist. Provide a valid source image.

Comment: As I've stated in the answer, this will not work because `DockerImageAsset` will not use the `latest` tag.

Comment: I removed the latest

sset_img = _asset.DockerImageAsset(self, "galactus_transformer_image", directory=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "../galactus_transformer")) _lambda.DockerImageFunction(self, id='gt_from_image', function_name="gt_from_image_Fn", code=_lambda.DockerImageCode.from_ecr(repository=asset_img.repository))

Comment: If you don't specify a `tag` argument in `from_ecr()`, you can see from documentation that it will just use `latest` as the default value.

Comment: I am ok with the default tag but fails create Lambda because image doesn't exist under /aws-cdk/assets. Do I have to use /assets in the docker file as a home folder

Comment: It doesn't exist because `DockerImageAsset` does not tag any images with the `latest` tag, as stated above. There is no `latest` tag in the repository. Consider using `DockerImageCode.from_image_asset()`.

Comment: DockerImageCode.from_image_asset() -- using this, will it create a new image, that is what I understood from reading the was document. is there anyway I can use the image created by DockerImageAsset() to create a lambda.

Comment: You can create one `DockerImageCode` object and reuse it across your lambdas.

Comment: is there any way to create a lambda using image created by DockerImageAsset

Comment: I am able to finally create the lambda from the DockerImageAsset image. Below is the code.

asset_img = _asset.DockerImageAsset(self, "test_image",                                            directory=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "../gt"))
    
 _lambda.DockerImageFunction(self, id='gt_from_image', function_name="gt_from_image_Fn",
                                    code=_lambda.DockerImageCode.from_ecr(
                                        repository=asset_img.repository,
                                        tag=asset_img.source_hash))

Comment: Consider adding that as an answer, explaining why it works, and accepting it.